# Laravel css not working for another page

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, laravel

I have a laravel first set the layout main page calling it as `app.blade.php` and stored it in `resources/views/layouts` and in it have this line  `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base1.css" />` and I stored this `css` in the the public/css folder.

Next in this folder say I have this `form1.blade.php` and at the very top I have this line `@extends('layouts.app')`. Here the form Here the .css comes out very well.

Next I submit this page and goes into the next blade called as `details.blade.php` and at the very top I have this too `@extends('layouts.app')` but I get this error `404 Not Found http://localhost:8000/student/css/base1.css`. In fact I did not anything new I just took the `form1`, copy and rename as details. In the `form1` I did the form submission action as `action="student/details"`  So what could be wrong or need to be done in this case?

Please show me what is duplicate to which question for me to defend on this? Its not fair to just mark it duplicate?

Comment: Please, before you do anything else, research how relative URLs versus absolute URLs work. You really need to know that.

Comment: Please show me where and what is duplicated here ?

Comment: you should use `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset("css/base1.css")}}" />`

Comment: Can you put that as the answer so that other can benefit it?

Comment: You can use like as : <link href="{{ URL::asset('/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >


                             and check your css path.

Comment: @user5313398 Nitesh's answer is the same idea as the duplicate (slightly different syntax, but same fix). Again, look into how URLs work and the difference between `/foo/bar` and `foo/bar` in how browsers handle it.